# Azure Application Insights Analytics Query for exporting to Power BI

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights

I need some help for writing queries in AI Analytics with which i can generate kusto query and export the result to Power BI . I am new to query language in general ( didn't have much exp in sql also )

So , I have created a  couple of custom events( lets say statusA and statusB ) in my app , which i will be getting in Customdimensions .  statusA and StatusB will be having lets say true or false . I should be able to get the result data as Status containing count of true/false values of StatusA and statusB each , so that i will be able to render it in a piechart.

the query which i tried  :

> customEvents  | extend queryA = customDimensions.['StatusA'] , queryB
>   = customDimensions.['StatusB'] | where queryA = true or queryB = true | project queryA, queryB | summarize count() by queryA , queryB

[Result I got is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xe25.jpg)

I want the result to be like this in pie chart :
   [Pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi76I.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
customEvents 
| extend queryA = tostring(customDimensions.['StatusA']) , queryB = tostring(customDimensions.['StatusB'])
| extend status = iff(queryA == 'true', "StatusA", (iff(queryB == 'true', "StatusB", "N/A")))
| summarize count() by status
| render piechart
```

To save this overhead of comparing values, you can simply report in the customDimensions on queryType and assign it with the value of QueryA or QueryB. Then it would be only a matter of using summarize count() by queryType.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be converting those true/falses into ints using iff, and then summing.

Try:

```
customEvents 
| extend queryA = tostring(customDimensions.['StatusA']) , queryB = tostring(customDimensions.['StatusB'])
| extend queryACount = iff(queryA == 'true', 1, 0)
| extend queryBCount = iff(queryB == 'true', 1, 0)
| summarize sum(queryACount),  sum(queryBCount)
| render piechart
```

Comment: I am getting the error like "The Pie Chart can't be created as you are missing a column of type String" . I am getting the counts in 2 columns for each query , actually  I want result set as one column "Status" having values "StatusA" and "statusB" with their counts .

Comment: My mistake - my query is no good for a piechart. How about this: | extend status = iff(queryA =='true' and queryB == 'false', "statusA", "statusB") | where queryA = true or queryB = true | summarize count() by status | render piechart